# Sum cells based on identical values in another column and place sum in specific spot

Tags: excel, formula

[Sample Excel image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmsOz.jpg)
Please see attached sample image.  I have identical but unique ID Numbers in cells A2:A10, and adjacent Values in cells B2:B10.  THEN, there's another string of identical but unique ID Numbers in cells A11:A15 with adjacent Values in cells B11:B15. This grouping pattern continues far down the Sheet.
I would like a drag-down formula in column C to sum all the Values from column B based on the identical ID numbers from column A, and place that total in cell C2.  The next sums would be placed in cells C11 and C16 based on my sample image.

Answer (score 1):

Put SUMIF in an IF:

```
=IF(A2<>A1,SUMIF(A:A,A2,B:B),"")
```

Put that in C2 and copy down.

[image]